# Selenium :This version of OperaDriver only supports Opera version 80 (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, opera

So, i've been trying to launch an opera browser with selenium but this is pretty complicated.

First, it canno't find the path, it was hard but i found something that worked with this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Opera(executable_path=r'D:\Prog\Opera\operadriver_win64\operadriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

And then, i got an other problem, i got this :

```
SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of OperaDriver only supports Opera version 80
  (Driver info: operadriver=80.0.3987.100 (3f00c26d457663a424865bbef1179f72eec1b9fe-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#864}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)`
```

So i tried to add the module webdriver-manager to correct this error but it doesn't work.
Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.opera import OperaDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install()) # this line was supposed to correct the problem but it doesn't 
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

I made some research on the internet, and a lot of things were talking about the operadriver and the browser version, so my Opera Browser version is the last one (71.0.3770.198) and spyder tells me that this driver only supports opera version 80 but i don't think it exists. I got the opera driver here : https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases
It says that it should work with my version of Opera so i kinda don't understand

Comment: Opera is based on Chromium, whose latest version is 85. The Opera webdriver names match the Chromium versions. The driver you downloaded is too old, targeting Opera 67. The latest driver version is 85. The release page explains which Opera version each driver is for

Comment: it still doesn't work, i really don't understand why

Comment: After the driver is updated and browser is updated still if it does not work, then will suggest to re-install your opera browser and get the driver again. It may work

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest driver, version 85.0.4183.102, which targets Opera Stable 71.

Opera is based on Chromium, whose latest version is 85. The Opera webdriver names match the Chromium versions. The [release page explains](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases) which Opera version each driver is for. The driver you downloaded is too old, targeting Opera Stable 67.

Comment: Nah, it still doesn't work, i got the same error message, (a little bit different tho), i got this : 

```session not created: This version of OperaDriver only supports Opera version 85
  (Driver info: operadriver=85.0.4183.102 (ffe848af6a5df4fa127e2929331116b7f9f1cb30-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1770}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)```